# How to properly tell a customer he/she is not allowed to modify software interface?

Tags: phrases, expressions

How can I properly tell a customer that, although he/she knows how to do it and he/she has the possibility, he/she is not allowed, by contract, to modify the layout of the software we just sold him?

First thing we came up with was:

```
Sir/Madam, no visual changes are allowed in our system.
```

But this seems so short, too concise. I was looking for something more formal, prolix.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Formal in what sense? If you're on a contract-enforcement tack, then I suggest getting a company attorney to draft an appropriate letter.  If it's more of a customer relations angle then simpler is probably better, but instead of a message that boils down to "you can't", you might get a better response from one that amounts to "you agreed not to do."

Comment: Define "*properly*".

Comment: Totally agree with this: `customer relations angle then simpler is probably better, but instead of a message that boils down to "you can't", you might get a better response from one that amounts to "you agreed not to do.`

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about saying unapproved changes will **void the warranty or support agreement**?

Apple put it this way ...

> Apple strongly cautions against installing any software that hacks iOS. It is also important to note that unauthorized modification of iOS is a violation of the iOS end-user software license agreement and because of this, Apple may deny service for an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch that has installed any unauthorized software. - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201954

And maybe you should get advice from a lawyer!

Comment: While I agree and like your answer, our problem is not about giving the customer support should he/she need it, but the fact that changing the interface would `destroy our brand's identity`... Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Why should your customer care about your brand identity ? that's why I think you need to motivate them in a different way (such as saying it may invalidate warranty)

Comment: But perhaps we're getting off topic for this site.

Comment: Oh, yes, good point! We care, they don't hehehe... Your answer is good and provides a good path for our statement/response, I'll accept your answer!